# Doctrine 2. Persisting Entity giving exception

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

```
/**
 * Some\ApiBundle\Entity\FileTagRel
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="file_tag_rel")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class FileTagRel extends AuditedBaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @var integer $fileId
     * @ORM\Column(name="file_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    protected $fileId;

    /**
     * @var integer $fileTagId
     * @ORM\Column(name="file_tag_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    protected $fileTagId;
    ...
    //Getters and setters
    ...

}
```

I'm simply trying to save the entity this way

```
$ftrEm = $this->doctrine->getEntityManagerForClass('Some\ApiBundle\Entity\FileTagRel');
$ftr = new FileTagRel();
$ftr->setFileId($newFile->getId());
$ftr->setFileTagId($tagId);
$ftr->setCreatedAt($newFile->getCreatedAt());
$ftr->setModifiedAt($newFile->getModifiedAt());
$ftr->setCreatedByUserId($newFile->getCreatedByUserId());
$ftr->setModifiedByUserId($newFile->getModifiedByUserId());
$ftrEm->persist($ftr);
$ftrEm->flush();
```

I'm getting this error -  `Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given`
I've foreign key relation in the db schema but haven't specified any mappings in the entity. I've no idea why I'm getting this error.

Comment: You might want to add the code were `spl_object_hash()` is actually used or the total error.

Comment: As Mats says, you have to add your call to `spl_object_hash()` here and also let's us able to see the "parameter-lifetime" (from "birth" to use into that call)